# I am trying to show pause button in second activity

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

My MainActivity java file

```
  package com.example.lenovo.infinity.app;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout btn;
ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;

private AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adsView);
    //adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //set font to text view
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.start_Text);
    Typeface custom = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(custom);

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Game java file

```
   package com.example.lenovo.infinity.app;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
   public class Game extends Activity {

View pauseButton;
RelativeLayout Rel_main_game;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    final int heights = dm.heightPixels;
    final int widths = dm.widthPixels;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    pauseButton = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pause,null,false);
    pauseButton.setX(widths - 250);
    pauseButton.setY(0);

    Rel_main_game.addView(pauseButton);

    pauseButton.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
    pauseButton.getLayoutParams().width = 250;
}
}
```

In my project, I have three layouts: the first, layout is main activity which has start button, the second layout is game panel which contains a pause button and button is the third layout

the XML files are 
First XML, this xml have start button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/game_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bg" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_marginBottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/StartBtn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_game"
            android:id="@+id/start_Text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adsView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5303974617236905/1000694879" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second XML, this contains the main game panel with pause button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rel_main_game"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.infinity.app.Game">

</RelativeLayout>
```

The third layout is a pause button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.infinity.app.Pause"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pauseImage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/pause_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="II"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pause_text_size"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lenovo.infinity.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Game"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```html
04-04 19:47:25.021 8325-8432/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package com.example.lenovo.infinity.app:1. Hash: e93251d423a7add58a3428a9e259cdd8b57c335ec3a30cc9897279fdeed6e512
04-04 19:47:25.021 8325-8432/? D/k: Found info for package com.example.lenovo.infinity.app in db.
04-04 19:47:25.235 514-703/? V/ActivityManager: com.example.lenovo.infinity.app/.MainActivity: task=TaskRecord{41c684b8 #132 A com.example.lenovo.infinity.app U 0}
04-04 19:47:25.774 8409-8409/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.infinity.app/com.example.lenovo.infinity.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.lenovo.infinity.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-04 19:47:25.782 514-531/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.lenovo.infinity.app/.MainActivity
04-04 19:47:25.789 131-131/? I/BufferQueue: [Starting com.example.lenovo.infinity.app](this:0x41f78008,api:2) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-04 19:47:25.803 131-14023/? I/BufferQueue: [Starting com.example.lenovo.infinity.app](this:0x41f78008,api:2) [queue] fps:0.28, dur:3530.34, max:3530.34, min:3530.34
04-04 19:47:25.820 131-204/? I/SurfaceTexture: [Starting com.example.lenovo.infinity.app](this:0x41f91558,api:2) [void* android::SurfaceTexture::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&)]
04-04 19:47:25.943 8409-8454/? D/dalvikvm: open_cached_dex_file : /data/data/com.example.lenovo.infinity.app/cache/ads1962259775.jar /data/data/com.example.lenovo.infinity.app/cache/ads1962259775.dex
04-04 19:47:26.024 514-535/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{41cae560 u0 Application Error: com.example.lenovo.infinity.app}
04-04 19:47:26.024 514-534/? I/WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{41cae560 u0 Application Error: com.example.lenovo.infinity.app}
```

Logcat

Comment: what's happening when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same botton for both start and pause botton:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pauseImage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/pause_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn" />
```

Change it for:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pauseImage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/pause_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_pause" />
```

where `btn_pause`is the source of the pause image.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using any button. what I want to do, I want to show the third layout as a pause button in the second layout. But, when I am running app on my cell I get this error in Logcat

Comment: I have posted error also please check and tell me where am i wrong

Comment: In onCreate the view is not created yet and you are trying to modify the RelativeLayout which is not still created. There is your problem

Answer (score 0):

In the second xml you mentioned that you have pause button but the snippet you posted has relative layout only. Use Framelayout if you want to show button on top of the other view.

Also in third xml, you need to change the src to pause image reference. currently you are referring to the same btn image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in mainActivity

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.StartBtn);
        btn = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Start_layout);
```